# Interfaz grafica utilizando Gif con PyQt5 en chatbot

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.8, gif

me encuentro trabajando en la programación de un chatbot utilizando Python 3.8 y PyQt5, pero he encontrado dos problemas que no he podido superar:

1. El primero ocurre con el script de python, al enviar un comando por voz, el script realiza la acción solicitada, pero al terminar de hacerlo, repite esta accion, es decir, que al solicitarle que me diga la hora o mi número telefónico, responde y lo hace indefinidamente hasta que recibe otro comando distinto que funciona pero hace lo mismo, repetirse indefinidamente.
2. El segundo problema consiste en que la interfaz gráfica funciona sólo al inicio de la ejecución del script, es decir, inicializo el script, recibo un saludo del bot y se abre la interfaz, completamente funcional y con el gif animado reproduciéndose, pero el resto del chatbot se detiene hasta no cerrar la ventana de la interfaz, al cerrarla el chatbot funciona normalmente salvo el primer problema que cité arriba.

Intenté las soluciones propuestas que se relacionan con estos problemas especialmente con la consideración de que tal vez estoy generando un método o función bloqueante en el caso del gif en la interfaz gráfica, pero encuentro que el problema sigue aún con la creación de un hilo para ejecutar la función bloqueante: el gif se reproduce dentro de la interfaz gráfica, pero mi programa principal permanece inactivo hasta que cierro la interfaz.

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda o comentarios que me proporcionen.

Reduje el código al mínimo:

```
from AssistantGif_ui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel
from PyQt5.Qt import QMovie
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pyjokes
import datetime
import time


listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty("rate", 130)
volume = engine.getProperty('volume')
engine.setProperty('volume', volume-0.1)
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)
now = datetime.datetime.now()

class Nueva(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     
        self.setupUi(self)  
        self.I = QLabel(self)
        self.I.resize(450,500)
        self.movi = QMovie("original.gif")
        self.I.setMovie(self.movi)
        self.movi.start()

        theline = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self) 
        theline.move(600, 140)  

app = QApplication([])
n = Nueva()
n.resize(900,500)
n.show()

def speak(audio):
    print('Assistant: ' + audio)
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def timeSett():
    currentH = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if currentH >= 0 and currentH < 12:
        speak('Good Morning!')

    if currentH >= 12 and currentH < 18:
        speak('Good Afternoon!')

    if currentH >= 18 and currentH != 0:
        speak('Good Evening!')

timeSett()

def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('Listenning...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            global command  
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice, language='en-english')
            command = command.lower()
            if 'Assistant' in command:
                command = command.replace('Assistant','')
                print(command) 
                
    except:
        pass
    return command
app.exec_()

def run_Assistant():
    command =  take_command()
    print('command')

    if 'what time is it' in command:
        print("Current date and time : ")
        print(now.strftime("The time is %H:%M"))
        speak(now.strftime("The time is %H:%M"))
        engine.runAndWait()
    elif 'goodbye' in command:
        print("Hasta la vista... Baby!")
        speak("Hastala vista...Baby!")         
        exit()
    elif 'what is my phone number' in command:
        print('xx xx xx xx xx is your phone number sir') 
        talk('xx xx xx xx xx is your phone number sir')
    elif 'tell me a joke' in command:
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke('en'))
    elif 'what time is it' in command:
        print("Current date and time : ")
        print(now.strftime("The time is %H:%M"))
        speak(now.strftime("The time is %H:%M"))
        engine.runAndWait() 
    else:
        talk('just now im not ready for this')

while True:
  run_Assistant()
```

Answer (score 0):

En el desarrollo de ésta interfaz gráfica, encontré que puedo crear una ventana emergente que solicita confirmación del usuario para ejecutar cualquier comando por voz, v.gr., si pregunto la hora al chatbot, se despliega una ventana emergente con el gif animado y un botón que solicita la ejecución del comando, al presionarlo, se cierra la ventana y en el intérprete de Python se muestra la respuesta y se ejecuta el comando, la ventana se abre cada vez que se proporciona un nuevo comando, mostrando el gif en movimiento, y se cierra al presionar el botón de confirmación, no es la solución que busco pero sé que lo haré pronto, publico ésta respuesta esperando que sea de utilidad para cualquier usuario que desarrolle un trabajo similar.

Este es el código:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from AssistantGif_ui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel
from PyQt5.Qt import QMovie
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pyjokes
import datetime
import time
import sys #Importamos módulo sys
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets #Importamos módulo uic y Qtwidgets

qtCreatorFile = "AssistantGif.ui" # Nombre del archivo UI aquí.

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile) #El modulo ui carga el archivo

class VentanaPrincipal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow): #Abrimos la ventana
    def __init__(self): #Constructor de la clase
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self) #Constructor
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self) #Constructor
        self.setupUi(self) # Método Constructor de la ventana
        self.I = QLabel(self)
        self.I.resize(450,500)
        self.movi = QMovie("original.gif")
        self.I.setMovie(self.movi)
        self.movi.start()

        the_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self) #  Open a box to write
        the_line.move(550, 140) #  Changes the location of the box
        the_line.resize(200,25)
        the_line.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")


        
        #Aquí irá nuestro código funcional
listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty("rate", 130)
volume = engine.getProperty('volume')
engine.setProperty('volume', volume-0.4)
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)
now = datetime.datetime.now()



def speak(audio):
    print('Assistant: ' + audio)
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def timeSett():
    currentH = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if currentH >= 0 and currentH < 12:
        speak('Good Morning!')

    if currentH >= 12 and currentH < 18:
        speak('Good Afternoon!')

    if currentH >= 18 and currentH != 0:
        speak('Good Evening!')

timeSett()

def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('Listenning...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            global command  
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice, language='en-english')
            command = command.lower()
            if 'Assistant' in command:
                command = command.replace('Assistant','')
                print(command)

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            app =  QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
            window = VentanaPrincipal()
            window.show()
            app.exec_()

                
                
    except:
        pass
    return command

                            


def run_Assistant():
    command =  take_command()
    print('command')

    if 'what time is it' in command:
        print("Current date and time : ")
        print(now.strftime("The time is %H:%M"))
        speak(now.strftime("The time is %H:%M"))
        engine.runAndWait()
    elif 'goodbye' in command:
        print("Hasta la vista... Baby!")
        speak("Hastala vista...Baby!")         
        exit()
    elif 'what is my phone number' in command:
        print('xx xx xx xx xx is your phone number sir') 
        talk('xx xx xx xx xx is your phone number sir')
    elif 'tell me a joke' in command:
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke('en'))
    elif 'goodbye' in command:
        print("Hasta la vista... Baby!")
        speak("Hastala vista...Baby!")         
        exit()
    else:
        talk('just now im not ready for this')




while True:
    run_Assistant()
```

[image: Y una pequeña imagen de su funcionamiento:]